# Laravel 5.1 application setup with existing source code

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Am trying to setup laravel application, but it is displaying only laravel default page. not able to run the application.
i have followed below steps.
1)dump the code in xamp\htdocs\sample(application folder name) and updated db details
in command prompt
2) composer update
3)php artisan up
4)php artisan serve

after serve command it is  displaying as "Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/

```
[Tue Jan 30 14:58:23 2018] ::1:51377 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Jan 30 14:58:26 2018] ::1:51380 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Jan 30 14:59:51 2018] ::1:51384 [200]: /favicon.ico
```

in browser http://localhost:8000/ displaying laravel defaule page.
please let me know how to setup the application and if i miss anything in above steps.
thanks in advance.

Comment: do you executed `npm install`?

Comment: Yes gulp n bower also

Comment: If laravel show default page, installation completed fine. What errors have occurred when you try to run your custom routes?

Comment: @Nikita : its not showing any errors. for all routes it showing default page only.

Comment: Do you installed authentication? (`pa make:auth`) Do you have `Auth::routes()` in your web.php?

Comment: @Nikita : no idea on this pls let me know how to do that

Comment: Open `routes/web.php` and try to find `Auth::routes()` if you will find it. That can mean that your requests processed by Middleware.  You should read documentation about authentication in this case.

Comment: web.php is not their in my application.

Comment: `app/Http/routes.php` Sorry web.php is for next versions

Comment: even routes.php also not their in my application

Comment: please [read about routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing) and check your routes

Comment: If you can see the the default laravel page then you are all set up. What is the problem?